# TestNG blocking?

Tags: testng, eclipse-mars

My default suite of unit tests blocked after only 14 unit tests using (TestNG Eclipse Mars) no errors in the console.

Blocked like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In all likelihood this is not a TestNG problem but perhaps a problem with either your code under test, an individual test you've written, or your `@After***` annotated methods.

The most logical place to start is to begin stepping through with a debugger your tests suite with breakpoints beginning on any `@After***` annotated methods that should invoked after your tests in question ends.

*If* it's blocking after a specific test is run, then try setting `@Test(enabled=false)` on that test and see if you can recreate the issue.  If your tests complete successfully after disabling that test, then that test or the code it exercises is your culprit.

Failing all of that, it may also be helpful to run your tests from the command line just to rule out any interesting issues from your IDE.

If none of those things makes the issue obvious, file an issue with the testng project at [their issues page on Github](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues)

Comment: thx for your comment,but when i run each classe individually it work fine

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you're running the latest testng version
- Remove all existing breakpoints
- Remove other versions of testing jars.Keep only latest testng jar
- Put the debug value as -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m in eclipse configuration settings file.

Please provide more information about your problem none of above helps.

Comment: it was SGBD probleme when i run my fixtures. thx for your comment :).